# How do i add items to a generic collection?

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections

Given:

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(ICollection<T> source)
{
    Customer c = new Customer();
    ....
    source.Add(c);
}
```

except `c` is not of type `<T>`.

So how do i add an item to a generic collection?

---

i *tried* having:

```
public static void DoStuff(ICollection<Human> source)
{
    Customer c = new Customer();
    ....
    source.Add(c);
}
```

but i don't use it because nobody can call `DoStuff`:

```
ICollection<Customer> c;
DoStuff(c); <---error
```

because something about *covariance*, and .NET doesn't realize that `Customer` descends from `Human`:

```
class Customer : Human {}
```

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with elements contained in `source`, or do you just want the collection populated?  Would it be possible to just return a newly created collection?

Comment: i'm not populating a new list, i'm modifying (adding, modifying, deleting) items in the passed list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just so you know *why* you get that error, an `ICollection<Customer>` can not be passed to an `ICollection<Human>` because they are not the same thing.  Think of it this way, if you had an `ICollection<Human>` you could `Add(new Deadbeat())` if `Deadbeat` derived from `Human`.

The other answers on ways to avoid your issue with a generic solves your problem (so they should get the answer credit):

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(ICollection<T> source) where T : new()
{
    T c = new T();
    ...
    source.Add(c);
}
```

but I just wanted to throw this answer out to explain *why* you get that error.  Think of it, if you could pass a collection of `Customer` as a collection of `Human`, it would let you add ANY kind of human, and this would violate the original collection.

Thus, even though `Customer` extends `Human`, this does not mean that `ICollection<Customer>` extends `ICollection<Human>` and `ICollection<T>` is not covariant/contravariant because it uses `T` for both `in` and `out` operations.

Answer (score 7):

should be just:

```
T t = new T();
....
source.Add(t);
```

Also you will have to add the [`new` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) to guarantee that `T` has a public parameterless constructor:

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(ICollection<T> source) where T: new()
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Would there be any recommendation on how to accomplish what i want? i don't think i can set the properties of my **T** customer with that syntax.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Do you want to specify all Customer properties?  Or just Human ones?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(ICollection<T> source)
    where T : new()
{
    T c = new T();
    source.Add(c);
}
```